# Undefined offset when trying to get the next position in php

Tags: php

error message when trying to print the next position in loop?

```
$coba = "testing"; 
for($h=1;$h<(count($coba));$h++){
    echo $coba[$h+1];
}
```

Comment: string treated as char array, the index is from 0, not 2

Comment: What you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code, you would get that error:

```
$coba = "testing"; 
for($h=1;$h<strlen($coba);$h++){
    echo $coba[$h+1];
}
```

The reason is you're trying to print something that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing $h to a number greater than the array.  That's why you are getting the offset error.

Comment: `$h` is never incrementing with that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Original code is incorrect here --> `for($h=1;$h<(**count**($coba));$h++){`

See the PHP reference guide for difference in count() and strlen().

count($coba)  is 1

strlen($coba) is 7

If you use strlen then the code would correctly loop through the string:

```
$coba = "testing"; 
for($h=1;$h<strlen($coba);$h++){
    echo $coba[$h+1];
}
```

Now, regarding the error you mentioned, when I run the above I get:

> PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: ...

Two problems here with your original code. Since I do not know your original intent, I can only guess at what you were trying to do with the loop.

Problem #1: indexing into the string should start with 0, not 1

Problem #2: $coba[$h+1] will be an invalid index at the END of the array at h+1.

You can either adjust the indexing h+1 to just be h OR
change the loop to loop 1 less via `for($h=0;$h<(strlen($coba)-1);$h++){`

Thus, final code could look like:

```
$coba = "testing";
for($h=0;$h<(strlen($coba)-1);$h++){
    echo $coba[$h+1];
}
```

Which outputs when run:

> esting

Comment: You might want to provide links on `count()` and `strlen()`, since you mentioned "the PHP reference guide"

Comment: well .. thats just part of my code. i don't show full of code. Thank a lot for the comment .. i will try it :)